# Error - Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to implement redux and throw and object into the store.  I get the correct object when I call the action but when I call store.dispatch() the store is never updated.  It only contains initial state. I think I've tried everything and am missing something small.  Any help would be appreciated!
[repo](https://github.com/asfopoo/habe)

signUp.js

```
import {getUsers} from "../actions/getUsersActions";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import store from '../store';

class SignMo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }

  }

  async getUsers () {
    await this.props.getUsers()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({users: response.users.users});
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    console.log('store =>', store.getState())
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers = this.getUsers.bind(this);
    this.getUsers();
  }

  render(){
     return(
       <stuff/>
    )
  }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { users } = state;

  return {
    users: users,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>  ({
  getUsers: () => store.dispatch( getUsers() )
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SignMo);
```

getUsersReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import {USERS_FAILURE} from "../actions/getUsersActions";
import {USERS_SUCCESS} from "../actions/getUsersActions";

let INITIAL_STATE ={
  users:[],
  isloading: false,
  errorResponse: false,
  errorMessage: null,
};

const getUsersReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // Take all returned user info and put it in store
    case USERS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        //type: USERS_SUCCESS,
        isLoading: false,
        errorResponse: false,
      };
    // Extract error message to display
    case USERS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        errorResponse: true,
        errorMessage: action.error
      };
    // Don't think this gets called
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default combineReducers({
  users: getUsersReducer
});
```

getUsersReducer

```
import axios from "axios";


const url = "http://localhost:3333";

export const USERS_SUCCESS = "USERS_SUCCESS";
export const USERS_FAILURE = "USERS_FAILURE";

export const usersSuccess = users => {
  return {
    type: USERS_SUCCESS,
    users
  };
};

export const usersFailure = error => {
  return {
    type: USERS_FAILURE,
    error
  };
};

export const getUsers = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios
      .get(`${url}/users`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('success', JSON.stringify(response));
        return dispatch(usersSuccess(response.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('err', error.response.data.message);
        return dispatch(usersFailure(error.response.data));
      });
  };
};
```

store.js

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducer from "./reducer";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, thunk))
);

export default store;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from "./store";






export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login">
              <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/home">
            <div className='primaryContainer'>
            <EngagementBar/>
            <Home />
            </div>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/SignUp">
              <SignUp className="centerSignUp" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/Tags">
              <Tags />
            </Route>
              <Route path="/signMo">
                <SignMo />
              </Route>
            <Route path="/search">
              <div className="primaryContainer"><Search /></div>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/profile">
              <Profile />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/upload">
              <Upload />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/notifications">
              <Notifications />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/information">
              < Information />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/"> {/*must be last !!!*/}
              <Load />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I run in to this error all the time.  This is a lot of code you wrote out.  Can you put this into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or some functioning example so we can play around with it?

Comment: Ive edited to match the changes but my strore still only contains the initial state and is never updated

Comment: Are you still getting your initial error or is it now just the issue that the store is not updating?  Your actual `getUsers` function had a lot of `dispatch` statements in it.  I edited my answer...see if those new edits work.

Comment: I get dispatch is not defined -- in code and doesnt compile... do I need to import something

Comment: I changed it to `store.dispatch`...try that.  But then you do have to import the `store`.  I do that regularly as well.

Comment: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'USERS_SUCCESS' before initialization

Answer (score 0):

You have

```js
  throwInStore = () => {
    store.dispatch(
      this.props.getUsers()
    );
  };
```

But why are you dispatching here?  `this.props.getUsers()` is already an action dispatched to the store as defined in your `mapDispatchToProps`.  So its like saying `dispatch( dispatch( getUsers() ) )`.

Could also be an issue here:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      getUsers,
    },
    dispatch
  );
```

I don't see why you need the `bindActionCreators`.  I would rewrite like so:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>  ({
  getUsers: () => store.dispatch( getUsers() )
})
```

Also, now with the `dispatch` within your `mapDispatchToProps`, you can remove all your `return dispatch` from the `getUser` function.  You should really only have one `dispatch` keyword per action:

```js
export const getUsers = () => {
  return axios
    .get(`${url}/users`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('success', JSON.stringify(response));
      store.dispatch(usersSuccess(response.data));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('err', error.response.data.message);
      store.dispatch(usersFailure(error.response.data));
    });
};
```

Comment: ive never used sandbox but I threw it in there https://codesandbox.io/s/github/asfopoo/habe . I can make you a server quick thatll just return a user if you need/want it

Comment: Does the error tell you which function is causing the problem?  Usually when I get this error it will say where in the code the problem is arising...?

Comment: The above error occurred in the <SignMo> component:
    in SignMo (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at App.js:49)
    in Route (at App.js:48)
    in Switch (at App.js:32)
    in div (at App.js:31)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:30)
    in Provider (at App.js:29)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:8)